# Swiper slide display vertically but working horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, swiper.js

I try to make slider using idangerous Swiper.js with Handelbars. I set up swiper option as below

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
     slidesPerView: 3,
     direction: 'horizontal'   
  });
```

I tried change option such as

> freeMode: true
>  slidesPerColumn:1  
>  slidesPerColumnFill:
>   'row' 
>  autoHeight: true

but nothing fix the unintended vertical layout

[here is the my swiper image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl6Fo.png)

I want to all slides display in one row horizontally
I also change constantly style of swiper-container class and swiper-slide
but didn't find the way to make things in right order yet

Comment: Do you use the complete css from swiper plugin?

Comment: @kmgt I Use this css from style tag i reffered to Multiple Slides Per View Demo from Swiper Api Docs
   .swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: #fff;
      /* Center slide text vertically */
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      --and so on--
    }

Comment: Try setup an example on jsfiddle. Sounds like a CSS issue, but it's impossible to tell without seeing your code

Comment: Has this issue been solved? I am encountering the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case problem was that **I used wrong loaders for css in webpack**.
When I add

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
},
```

for webpack config, it solved the problem.
Don`t forget run

```
npm install --save-dev style-loader css-loader
```

My js code

```
import Swiper from 'swiper';
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css';
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container');
```

My html

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and fixed it by adding `style="align-items: center"` to `swiper-wrapper`

https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/issues/1513